# PHP PregEX for detecting a variant

Tags: php, string

I am trying to create a registry expression that will detect the following syntax in a string:

```
OPEN-BRACKET > ANYTHING > PLUS-OR-MINUS > CLOSE-BRACKET
```

- Example String: NB###-#####-#####-###**[#+]**

Please note that the expression could be anywhere in the string and have multiple occurrences.

I have tried `[(.+)(\+|-)]` which doesn't seem to work as I imagined it to do in php, but does work in [rubular.com](http://rubular.com)

What would the expression be to return the **string** **and** whether it was a **plus** or **minus**?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `.+` consumes all due to the default [greedyness](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)? What happens if you anchor the string using `^\[(.+)(\+|-)\]$`.

If you cannot anchor the string due to multiply occurrences, try using [look-ahead feature](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). And if "ANYTHING" really can be anything, how do you distinguish an ANYTHING `+]`  from a PLUS-OR-MINUS > CLOSE-BRACKET?

If neither plus nor minus is allowed in ANYTHING, go for `\[([^+-]+)(\+|-)\]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the pattern:

```
"(\[(.+)(\+|-)\])"
```

The parentheses capture the whole group, the `\` escapes the `[` and `]` characters, and also the `+` character, that, otherwise (when unescaped) have special meanings in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I managed to figure out `/\[([\$|a-zA-Z]+)(\+|-)\]/` works as i intended it to.